# Tabbed sliders height changes on navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

[This](http://projectcocoa.in/?page_id=87) page has sliders in tabs but on navigating to other tabs slider size becomes small automatically.

What is the cause ?

Comment: Do you use thumbnails?